# How type recursive object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have next object

```
const obj = {
 name: 'First',
 age: 22,
}
```

This object has the next interface

```
interface ITask {
 name: string,
 age: number
}
```

but after some data mapping I create a recursive object like this

```
const obj = {
 name: 'First',
 age: 22,
 next: {
   name: 'Second',
   age: 12,
   next: { EMPTY OBJECT WHEN END }
 }
}
```

I try type this object this way, but it doesnt work

```
type IRecursiveTask =  {
        [key: string]: IRecursiveTask
} & ITask
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`type` defines a type aliases, and type aliases cannot reference themselves. However, `interface` can.

```
interface IRecursiveTask {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  next: IRecursiveTask | {};
}
```

Comment: The type should work, but the reason you describe is not the reason why. an `type` alias works just fine. https://tsplay.dev/mbAXPN This works because the type is recursive in a known property rather than index signature.

Comment: @AlexWayne, you should have put that as an answer!!!